# home and net drives appearing on Desktop

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, desktop

On my Desktop, there are two external drives that won't go away. They are named `home` and `net`. They are hidden drives, but I have hidden files set to show. Is there any way to get them to go away, and what are they? I am running Mac OS X Snow Leopard, but it was there under Leopard too (I did something to make them appear but I can't remember what.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hide the drives in Finder's preferences.

[image]

Uncheck **Hard disks**.

Comment: Actually, I had to uncheck just `Network drives`. But you let me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: You're most welcome!

Comment: For me, it was the 'Connected servers' that was the problem, displaying 'home' and 'net' icons. Thanks for the solution.